# Is there a "switch" tag available

Tags: twig

I just tried to use the `switch` tag on a twig template, on a Symfony 5 project and got an error.

Then looked for a solution on the web, found documentation, double checked my syntax, that was correct.
Finally, searched the twig vendor folders and didnt' found any `switch*.php` file.

I guess this is not available by default but can't believe it. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Although more verbose, you can achieve the same as you would in a switch in a series of `if ... elseif ... [elseif ...] else ...`

Answer (score 3):

No, `swicth` not exists in default Twig installation.
To use the `switch` statement you must implement it by yourself or use a bundle/package like `buzzingpixel/twig-switch`.

Comment: In twig it's called an extension